# Iproute2 Bridge With Netem and TC

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

I have a transmitter and a receiver who are supposed to send packets between them in multicast mode. I want to stress the receiver using netem and tc. My setup is as follows: the TX is connected to port eth0 of a linux machine which is then connected to the RX through port eth1. I want create a bridge between eth0 and eth1 and apply the tc commands on the bridge. I pinged the TX and RX from the linux machine with a delay command of 100ms on both ports to test the setup and I found out that eth1 does not apply the delay. I also noticed that the port eth1 is not in the list given but he following command:

```
sudo bridge -d -s mdb show
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!